# PlotLegends: size, position, type and font

Tags: plotting, legending

I have plot code something like this:

```
g1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006], Dashing[{.07, 0.02}]}];
g2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Thickness[0.006]}];
g3 = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.007], Dashing[{.01, 0.015}]}];
fig = Show[g1, g2, g3, AspectRatio -> 1.4]
```

That I simplify it, I want to use plotlegends, type "a=0.1" and "d=10" for g1 plot, "d=100" for g2 plot and "d=200" for g3 plot and control size and font and place of them.
the problem is, their is 4 information, one of them general and 3 of them related to each plot that they are different from the plot function i.e. "x, x^2 and x^3" and I want all of them inside one graph for example {Left, Top}.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it like this. It's better to use `AbsoluteDashing` and `AbsoluteThickness`. Add `LabelStyle -> {}` as an option for `LineLegend` to change font, colour and so on.

```
g1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[1], AbsoluteDashing[{20, 5}]},
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"a=0.1, d=10"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}], {Left,Top}]];
g2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> {Green, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"d=100"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}], {Left, Top}]];
g3 = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[1], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}]},
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"d=200"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}],{Left, Top}]];
fig = Show[g1, g2, g3, AspectRatio -> 1.4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works good!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help,

```
  g1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006], Dashing[{.07, 0.02}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{TraditionalForm["d=10"]}, {Left, Top}]]
  g2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.006], Dashing[{.07, 0.02}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{TraditionalForm["d=100"]}, {Left, Top}]]
  g3 = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Thickness[0.006], Dashing[{.07, 0.02}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{TraditionalForm["d=200"]}, {Left, Top}]]
  lText = Text[Style["a=0.1", Medium], {0.5, 0.89}];
  txt = Graphics[{lText}];
  Show[{g1, g2, g3, txt}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18], 
  Style["f(x)", FontSize -> 18]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Directive[FontSize -> 14]}, 
  Ticks -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I want to plot all 3 graphs in one graph and also for different d with their type that mentioned in code

Comment: @Sasan, Modified, Now take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works good!

Comment: @Sasan If it has helped you, then you may accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Manipulate[
 g1 = Plot[a x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[1], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{20, 5}]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"a"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}], {Left, 
      Top}]];
 g2 = Plot[b x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"b"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}], {Left, 
      Top}]];
 g3 = Plot[c x^3, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[1], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"c"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}], {Left, 
      Top}]];
 fig = Show[g1, g2, g3, AspectRatio -> 1.4],
 {{a, 0.1, "g1(a)"}, 0.1, 1, 0.1},
 {{b, 0.1, "g2(b)"}, 0.1, 1, 0.1},
 {{c, 0.1, "g3(c)"}, 0.1, 1, 0.1}
 ]
```

which gives much more flexibility to play with the plots by changing the parameters.

[image]