# LegendMarker in combination with Placed

Tags: legending

I am trying to change the Marker size in my legend when I am trying to use Placed. If I don't use Placed I was able to use LegendMarkerSize to change it (as shown by some answers on this site), but I can't seem to combine the two. Here is my output
[image]

As you can see the star in legend C is too small. LegendMarkerSize seems to change the box size which is allotted to drawing the marker instead of changing the marker size (notice the gap in between the asterisk and C). How can I change the legend marker size without changing the plot marker (while using Placed)?

Comment: See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183446/plotlegends-size-position-type-and-font/183449#183449).

Comment: It looks like LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10} just sets the size of the box (line when used with LineLegend). In my case, it doesn't increase my marker (*) size - it just changes the size of the box, which is allotted to drawing the asterisk. As we see in my original picture, the C comes a little right of my asterisk because it has a big blank box size to its left (if there was a line, that line would have been bigger)